# How to check whether a Paypal email id is US account or not using Paypal API

Tags: paypal

i would like to check whether a Paypal account(Paypal email id) is US account or non US account using Paypal API. Is it possible to check by Paypal API. If so let me know the documentation. Your suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could see `Login with PayPal` to get the buyer's country information.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#identity

```
GET /v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=<Schema>
```

Response includes [country](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#address-object-for-identity) object to determine if its US or not.